# Zabbix 2.2 calculate issue

Tags: zabbix

I need to agregate power data from 8 different PDUs.

So far:
- I've created a template with OIDs to poll by SNMP the desired value and I called it: Amps Total.
- I've created 8 different hosts using the template and it works OK. I can see the Amps Total being graphed for all the devices.
- I've created a fake host to use as "Data Centre" object.
- I've created a new template with 8 items Type "Calculate", Formula:
last("PDU-B1-L:Amps Total")+last("PDU-B1-R:Amps Total")

(PDU-B1-L & PDU-B1-R are my PDU hostnames).

I was expecting to see the agregate data (at least for the 2 PDUs), but nothing is being shown. All the data type is Numeric (Unsigned).

Those hosts are being polled through a Zabbix proxy. I replaced the hostname by proxy:host:key in the formula with no luck. (the host config shows proxy:host as the hostname)

Any clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use item keys in the calculated item formula. Given that spaces are not supported in item keys, "Amps Total" most likely is item name.